# How to modify the breaks of the legend of a contour plot using ggplot in R

Tags: ggplot2, contour

I have a dataframe of a contour and want to plot this contour as lines with colour gradient. For this purpose, I want to use ggplot. For the actual data, I need a divergent color bar to show positive and negative values.

For this purpose, I took a closer look at some of the functions of the [corr2D](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corr2D/index.html) package and simplified them a bit:

```
color.palette <- function(z, N = 32) {
  zlim <- range(z)
  
  if (N%%2 == 0){
    N <- N + 1
  }
  
  Where <- seq(-max(abs(zlim)), max(abs(zlim)), length.out = N) 
  OM <- which(Where < 0)
  OP <- which(Where > 0)
  
  COL <- rep("transparent", length(Where))
  COL[OM] <- fields::designer.colors(col = c("darkblue", "cyan"), n = length(OM))
  COL[OP] <- fields::designer.colors(col = c("yellow", "red", "darkred"), n = length(OP))
  COL[(N + 1)/2] <- "transparent"
  COL <- COL[which(zlim[1] < Where & Where < zlim[2])]
  Where <- seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length.out = length(COL))
  
  return(list(col = COL, breaks = Where))
}
```

With some artificial data, the plot looks fine at first glance.

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")

# get data

set.seed(230529)

z <- runif(n = 100, min = -5, max = 20)
x <- y <- seq(1, length(z)/10, 1)
tmp <- expand.grid(x, y)
x <- tmp[,1]
y <- tmp[,2]


df <- data.frame(x, y)
df$z <- z
df$level <- as.numeric(df$z)

# get color palette

N <- 32
palette <- color.palette(z = df$level, N = N)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level)),
               breaks = palette$breaks) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = palette$col)
```

[image: original levels]

If you take a closer look, you see, that the values at zero are not transparent, but rather cyan, since the value of zero is not included explicitely in the color breaks.

```
> palette$breaks
 [1] -4.8989238 -3.5170849 -2.1352460 -0.7534071  0.6284318  2.0102707
 [7]  3.3921096  4.7739485  6.1557874  7.5376263  8.9194652 10.3013041
[13] 11.6831430 13.0649819 14.4468208 15.8286597 17.2104986 18.5923375
[19] 19.9741764
> palette$col
 [1] "#00DDF0"     "#00EEF7"     "#00FFFF"     "transparent" "#FFFF00"    
 [6] "#FFD500"     "#FFAB00"     "#FF8400"     "#FF5F00"     "#FF3D00"    
[11] "#FF2100"     "#FF0900"     "#FB0000"     "#F00000"     "#E30000"    
[16] "#D40000"     "#C30000"     "#B10000"     "#9E0000"
```

My first try to change this, was to change the breaks according to the colors by slightly modifying the function

`Where <- Where[which(zlim[1] < Where & Where < zlim[2])]`

Now, the color for the value zero is transparent

```
> palette$breaks
 [1] -3.745158 -2.496772 -1.248386  0.000000  1.248386  2.496772  3.745158
 [8]  4.993544  6.241930  7.490316  8.738702  9.987088 11.235474 12.483860
[15] 13.732246 14.980632 16.229018 17.477404 18.725790
> palette$col
 [1] "#00DDF0"     "#00EEF7"     "#00FFFF"     "transparent" "#FFFF00"    
 [6] "#FFD500"     "#FFAB00"     "#FF8400"     "#FF5F00"     "#FF3D00"    
[11] "#FF2100"     "#FF0900"     "#FB0000"     "#F00000"     "#E30000"    
[16] "#D40000"     "#C30000"     "#B10000"     "#9E0000"
```

and therefore the plot also looks fine.

[image: equvidistant levels]

Now, the problem is, that the plot doesn't cover the whole data range.

```
> range(palette$breaks)
[1] -3.745158 18.725790
> range(df$level)
[1] -4.898924 19.974176
```

Therefore, I scaled the values for te breaks to the minimum and maximum values of the data in the function using

```
Where[which(Where < 0)] <- Where[which(Where < 0)]/min(Where[which(Where < 0)])*zlim[1]
Where[which(Where > 0)] <- Where[which(Where > 0)]/max(Where[which(Where > 0)])*zlim[2]
```

Now, the data ranges are equal and the value of zero is transparent,

```
> range(palette$breaks)
[1] -4.898924 19.974176
> range(df$level)
[1] -4.898924 19.974176

> palette$breaks
 [1] -4.898924 -3.265949 -1.632975  0.000000  1.331612  2.663224  3.994835
 [8]  5.326447  6.658059  7.989671  9.321282 10.652894 11.984506 13.316118
[15] 14.647729 15.979341 17.310953 18.642565 19.974176
> palette$col
 [1] "#00DDF0"     "#00EEF7"     "#00FFFF"     "transparent" "#FFFF00"    
 [6] "#FFD500"     "#FFAB00"     "#FF8400"     "#FF5F00"     "#FF3D00"    
[11] "#FF2100"     "#FF0900"     "#FB0000"     "#F00000"     "#E30000"    
[16] "#D40000"     "#C30000"     "#B10000"     "#9E0000"
```

but the plot looks not as expacted.

[image: full range, wrong levels]

**Question:**
What do I have to change to cover the whole measuring range and at the same time get a transparent color at zero?